# Technical question: how to build exe from python code?

Tags: python, programming

I have a predictive model in IPython notebook. How can I create dll or exe from it? And is it possible to save in executable file already trained model?

I want a program with very simple syntax(X - file with objects, out -- file with answers):

```
./model X out
```

I don't know if is appropriate community for this question. If not, I'll delete it.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to copy, or [convert](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/nbconvert.html)*, your IPython code (I think) into a Python script. After that you can use software such as [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) to create a standalone application. Other hypothesis are:

- [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)
- [pyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)
- [py2App](https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/) (Mac OsX)

It's possible to save data inside the scripts (it will be compiled the same way as code as long as it is valid). Other possibility is to save in an external file and just load the data on execution. If the data is in a class check [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to save it to a file.

- *as* @dmb *suggested.*

EDIT: Ah I forgot to mention the arguments. That is easily achievable. Check this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497370/making-exe-file-from-python-that-uses-command-line-arguments) in SO.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have read also http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html
However, I am still curious if it is possible to compile my script and to be able to execute it on systems that don't have scikit package.

Comment: @Acapello Yes you can although sometimes it takes some work (not just for scikit-learn). Check for instance this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505678/please-help-how-to-use-py2exe-when-it-include-sklearn or this https://sourceforge.net/p/scikit-learn/mailman/message/29974522/

Answer (score 2):

You can [convert](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/nbconvert.html) your ipython notebook to a variety of different formats. If I were you, I would convert it to a .py file, and organize your code to take in `sys.argv` 'X' and 'out' for reading and writing your data. Then at the CLI, you can type

`python ./model.py X out`